# .waitForElementVisible() alternative for change in value

Tags: javascript, automation, nightwatch.js

I've been running some JS tests using nightwatch and find the .waitForElementVisible() function very useful, however, the code I am testing has an element whose value changes after a button click and is always visible.

My issue is that the value change lags behind the button click (slow machine) so I have to put a long this.api.pause() to test the value in these cases.

Is there some sort of alternative function like waitForElementValueChange() that detects a change in the element value the same way waitForElementVisible() detects the element becoming visible?

Open to any creative solutions, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware there isn't a built in method that can detect element changes because you don't need to.

I will to it like this

```
const buttonBeforeClick = 'button[value = "Click Me!"]';     // just an example selectors
const buttonAfterClick = 'button[value = "Im Clicked!"]';   // use a page object for those
browser.waitForElementVisible(buttonBeforeClick);
browser.click(buttonBeforeClick );
browser.waitForElementVisible(buttonAfterClick);
```

There is no reason for it not to work, if an element has 2 "states" in our case "clicked" and "unClicked" you just capture both of them.